# reset the text area contents

Tags: java, applet, textarea, textfield

I have this code.. here when i input number "6" in the textfield, text should be displayed in the textarea..but after that if i input any other number i want the textarea contents to be clear. But when I execute my code, the old contents of the textarea remain even when i input a different number. Please help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
/* <applet code="front" width=500 height=500></applet> */
public class front extends Applet implements ActionListener {
  String msg="";
  TextArea text,text1;
  TextField txt;
  Button load, enter;

  public void init() {
    enter=new Button("Enter");
    load=new Button("Load");
    txt=new TextField(5);
    text=new TextArea(10,15);

    add(load);
    add(text);

    add(txt);
    add(enter);

    load.addActionListener(this);
    txt.addActionListener(this);
    enter.addActionListener(this);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
    String str = ae.getActionCommand();
    if(str.equals("Load")) {
      msg = "You pressed Load";
    } else {
      if(txt.getText().toString().equals ("6")) {
        msg="Set the text for 6";
        text.setText("Text");
      } else {
        msg="Invalid number";
        text.setText("");
      }
    }
    repaint();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString(msg,350,250);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm running this example on my computer and the TextArea clears if I type anything other than "6" is the textfield (if I type "6" it sets the textarea to "Text")

Comment: Do you mean you want the TextField to be cleared?

Comment: TextArea itseld..It does work..but it doesnt work all the time .. especially when there are two text areas.. is there a problem with my software or something?

Answer (score 2):

write your actionPerformed() method as follows

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
    String str = ae.getActionCommand();
    if(str.equals("Load")) {
      msg = "You pressed Load";
    } else {
      if(txt.getText().toString().equals ("6")) 
         {
        **text.setText("");**
        msg="Set the text for 6";
        text.setText("Text");
         } 
         else {
        msg="Invalid number";
        text.setText("");
      }
    }
    repaint();
  }
```

the mistake was that you were not clearing the text field after writing to it!
now it is cleared by using `text.setText("");` in `if` condition

hope this solves your problem!

Comment: No it doesnt :( it remains as "Text" itself..the thing is only the msg "Invalid msg" gets displayed but the textfield isnt cleared :(

Answer (score 0):

You should call `super.paint(g)` within `paint(Graphics g)` method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString(msg,350,250);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, `text.setText("");` will not do anything and it will same as `//text.setText("");`

So Better Approach is to take help of ASCII code,

For Null Character ASCII value is `0`, in unicode we can write it as `'\u0000'`

And Finally this Statement will surely work: `text.setText(""+'\u0000');`

Note: their is no method is textArea class to clear the area...
So you have to do this on your own.